# I can't print info from a nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

So I have a very big list of a nested dictionary, but I'm gonna use only a small info of them, for the example.

So I'm trying to print this nested dictionary:

```
MN = {}
count_ = 1
menu_category = "DESSERT"
mi_item = 'Cake'
mi_price = '$5.00'
mi_description = 'Eggs, Sugar'
MN[count_] = {menu_category:{mi_item:{'price':mi_price, 'description':mi_description}}}

MC = ''
for mi_id, mi_cat, mi_it in MN.items():
    for mc in mi_cat:
        if mc != MC:
            print(f'Menu Category: {mc}')
            print()
        else:
            MC = mc
            print(f"{mc[mi_it]}: ", end='')
            for m_it in mi_it:
                print(f"{m_it}: {mi_it[m_it]}", end='\n')
            print()
```

But I'm getting this Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\bilakos\Desktop\PYTHON_PROJECTS\test.py", line 9, in <module>
    for mi_id, mi_cat, mi_it in MN.items():
ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 2)
```

**What I'm doing wrong here?**

Comment: You can't do `for mi_id, mi_cat, mi_it in MN.items():` because `.items` just returns tuples of the form `(key, value)` so there are only two things to unpack

Comment: @CoryKramer So how I can unpack the info that I want?

Comment: I don't think there's a way to unpack a dictionary directly.

Comment: You need nested loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`items()` only iterates over the top level of the dictionary, not the nested dictionaries. So you need to write your own nested loop.

```
MC = ''
for mi_id, mi_cat in MN.items():
    for mc, mi in mi_cat.items():
        if mc != MC:
            print(f'Menu Category: {mc}')
            print()
            MC = mc
        for item_name, item_details in mi.items():
            print(f'  Item: {item_name}')
            print(f'    Price: {item_details["price"]}')
            print(f'    Description: {item_details["description"]}')
            print()
```

The part of the loop that prints the items details shouldn't be in `else:`, because you'll skip the first item of a new category.

Also, it seems like `MN` should be a list rather than a dictionary, since the order matters (you want all the items in the same category together). Or you should have another level of grouping.

Comment: Got this error:  File "c:\Users\bilakos\Desktop\PYTHON_PROJECTS\test.py", line 18
    print(f'    Price: {item_details['price']}')
                                      ^
SyntaxError: f-string: unmatched '['

Comment: Fixed it. Need to use `"` inside `f'`

Comment: If you change the `mi` to `mi.items()` then is working.
Thank you very much Barmar.